# Function pointer with a generic pointer parameter

Tags: c

I have an data structure that stores a generic `void *` for each node which gets casted to the correct type at the appropriate time. In the cleanup function for this object, I would then like to provide a callback so that this generic object can too be "cleaned up."

```
struct foo {
    void *data;
    // ...
};

void foo_cleanup(struct foo *foo, void (*data_cleanup)(void *data)) {
    data_cleanup(foo->data);
    // ...
}

// ...

void bar_cleanup(void *data) {
    struct bar *bar = (struct bar *)data;
    // ...
}
```

This works fine, however I would prefer if the signature of `bar_cleanup` referred to `bar` directly, rather than `void *`:

```
void bar_cleanup(struct bar *bar)
```

Of course, replacing that code as is creates "parameter type mismatch" warnings. Is there any way to achieve directly what I am trying to do, if not a similar method of achieving the same cleanup task?

Comment: nope, you're looking at the C method

Comment: The way you are currently doing it is the better way to do it.  Note that the cast inside the callback functions isn't necessary, though it is explicit to write it out.

Comment: `bar_cleanup` is never called in your code. It would be better to post a MCVE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing now is the correct way to deal with it.  Your desire to use pointers to cleanup functions with a specific type runs foul of the (strict) rules in C11 (and C99, and probably C90 though I've not formally checked C90).

> ### [§6.3] Conversions
>
> #### [§6.3.2.3 Pointers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3)
>
> ¶8 A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.

---

Your existing code is:

```
struct foo {
    void *data;
    // ...
};

void foo_cleanup(struct foo *foo, void (*data_cleanup)(void *data)) {
    data_cleanup(foo->data);
    // ...
}

void bar_cleanup(void *data) {
    struct bar *bar = (struct bar *)data;
    // ...
}
```

This code is clean and obeys the rules.  The pointer to the `bar` cleanup function has the signature `void (*)(void *)` which matches the pointer used by `foo_cleanup()`.  The cast in `bar_cleanup()` is optional but explicit.  Even if you omit the cast notation, that conversion will occur as C automatically converts from `void *` to `struct bar *`.

If you try to use the cleanup function:

```
void bar_cleanup(struct bar *bar);
```

you would have to make a call equivalent to:

```
struct foo foo37;
…code initializing foo37…
foo_cleanup(&foo37, (void (*)(void *))bar_cleanup);
```

This coerces the type of the function to a different pointer type.  Unless the code inside `foo_cleanup()` knows somehow (how?) that the pointer needs to use function with the signature `void (*)(struct bar *)` and changes it before calling the cleanup function, it runs afoul of the rule in §6.3.2.3.

```
foo_cleanup(struct foo *foo, void (*data_cleanup)(void *data))
{
    (*data_cleanup)(foo->data);    // Undefined behaviour
    if (data->…)
        (*(void (*)(struct bar *))data_cleanup)(foo->data);  // OK, but…
    …
}
```

The unconditional call is wrong because the types of the real function pointer and the one claimed by the parameter type are different.   The conditional call is clean because it casts the pointer back to its real type before calling the function.  (This is C; the conversion from `void *` to `struct bar *` is automatic and valid.) . However, having to know what to convert the pointer-to-function to in the `foo_cleanup()` function defeats the purpose of using a pointer-to-function in the first place.  It also isn't clear how `foo_cleanup()` does determine which cast is correct, and if you add a new type, you have to change the code again to support the new type.

All of this means that a solution using `void bar_cleanup(struct bar *bar)` is not really acceptable.

If you follow the strict rules laid down by the standard and still want to call `void bar_cleanup(struct bar *)`, you have to write gruesome, non-maintainable, inflexible code.

If you want absolutely reliable code, you will follow these rules and keep your existing code (`void bar_cleanup(void *data)`).  It has the beneficial side-effect of avoiding painful casts — function pointer casts are not pretty — and leaves the `foo_cleanup()` function unchanged regardless of how many different pointer types are stored in the `data` member of `struct foo` as long as the calling code knows which is the correct type (and if the calling code doesn't know, it's a case of "Abandon Hope All Ye Who Enter Here" anyway).

In practice, how serious a problem is this?  Actually, you'll probably get away with it at the moment.  But it is invoking undefined behaviour and compilers are ever eager to identify and exploit undefined behaviour to 'optimize' the code they generate.  You can do as you want without the cast in `foo_cleanup()`, but you are
taking risks which can be simply and painlessly avoided by keeping your current code.

Note that this applies to comparator functions passed to `qsort()` or `bsearch()` in the standard library.  Those functions should be written to take two `const void *` parameters and return an `int`.  Doing otherwise runs foul of §6.3.2.3.
There are examples in otherwise respected C books that do not keep to these strict rules.

Comment: So when trying to make a clean API, you're suggesting it's okay to have a `bool bar_create(struct bar *bar)` and `void bar_cleanup(void *data)` (as opposed to `void bar_cleanup(struct bar *bar)`)? The only concern I have with this is that I can call `bar_cleanup` with an arbitrary pointer and the compiler won't raise any warnings.

Comment: I am trying to make my code as strict/explicit as possible but I'm not all too familiar with C conventions, so "best practice" advice is as good as any

Comment: I'm saying that given the design of the polymorphic  cleanup, the `void *` is an unpleasant necessity to avoid undefined behaviour.  Using the 'correct type' in the function prototype won't help in the slightest — you'll be bludgeoning the compiler into accepting whatever you provide with casts, and if it doesn't go off the rails, you can still screw up royally and the compiler still won't be able to help you.  The casts tell the compiler "I know more than you do".

Comment: You could consider whether using one or more discriminated union types helps — but it complicates things and doesn't avoid all the problems.  Using the `void *` in the data structure opens the door for the problems.  Eliminate that and you can deal with the rest.  But while you have `void *data;` in the structure, you're open to making type mistakes in code that manipulates the structure.

Answer (score -1):

```
typedef void (*CLEANUP_FUNC)(void *);

void foo_cleanup(struct foo *foo, CLEANUP_FUNC *data_cleanup) {
    data_cleanup(foo->data);
    // ...
}

void bar_cleanup(struct bar *data) {
    // ...
}

foo_cleanup(foo, (CLEANUP_FUNC *)bar_cleanup);
```

---

The following is a full example featuring generic stack `Stack` and some elements of type `Foo`.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// ---

typedef void (STACK_DEALLOCATOR)(void *);

typedef struct Stack {
   STACK_DEALLOCATOR *element_deallocator;
   size_t num_elements;
   size_t num_allocated;
   void **elements;
} Stack;

Stack *Stack_New(STACK_DEALLOCATOR *element_deallocator) {
   Stack *this = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
   if (this == NULL)
      goto ERROR;

   this->element_deallocator = element_deallocator;
   this->num_elements = 0;
   this->num_allocated = 4;

   this->elements = malloc(sizeof(void *) * this->num_allocated);
   if (this->elements == NULL)
      goto ERROR2;

   return this;

   ERROR2: free(this);
   ERROR:  return NULL;
}

int Stack_Push(Stack *this, void *element) {
   if (this->num_elements == this->num_allocated) {
      // ...
   }

   this->elements[ this->num_elements++ ] = element;
   return 1;
}

void Stack_Destroy(Stack *this) {
   void **element = this->elements;
   for (size_t i=this->num_elements; i--; ) {
      this->element_deallocator(*(element++));
   }

   free(this->elements);
   free(this);
}

// ---

typedef struct Foo {
   int data;
   // ....
} Foo;


Foo *Foo_New(int data) {
   Foo *this = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
   if (this == NULL)
      return NULL;

   this->data = data;
   return this;
}

void Foo_Destroy(Foo *this) {
   free(this);
}

// ---

int main(void) {
   Stack *stack = Stack_New((STACK_DEALLOCATOR *)Foo_Destroy);
   if (stack == NULL) {
      perror("Stack_New");
      goto ERROR;
   }

   Foo *foo = Foo_New(123);
   if (foo == NULL) {
      perror("Foo_New");
      goto ERROR2;
   }

   if (!Stack_Push(stack, foo)) {
      perror("Stack_Push");
      goto ERROR3;
   }

   Stack_Destroy(stack);
   return 0;

   ERROR3: Foo_Destroy(foo);
   ERROR2: Stack_Destroy(stack);
   ERROR:  return 1;
}
```

Comment: So function pointer casting like that is okay? I was worried that this would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Brandon — it is OK to cast like that as long as you “uncast” before you call the function via the pointer. If you call the function via the cast pointer, you invoke undefined behaviour (so bad things might, but probably won’t, happen).  You’re best off making the callback functions take the `void *` argument and only doing the conversion to the specific pointer in the callback function. That doesn’t need an explicit cast, though the conversion occurs implicitly.

Comment: This answer should cover the necessary casting within `foo_cleanup`